# k connected graph,none of edge contraction is k connected.

Tags: graph-theory

For each integer k≥4, find a k-connected graph G on at least k+2 vertices, none of whose edge contractions is k-connected.

for k=4, I found complete graph with 6 vertices, some other graphs, but for other k, I have no idea. thanks for any hints...

Are all K_k, complete graph with k vertices, right?

Comment: I don't think the complete graph with $6$ vertices has this property. If you contract an edge, you get a complete graph with $5$ vertices, which is still $4$-connected.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, yes, you are right, my example is 4-regular graph with  6 vertices. Can we send a photo in this site?? for k=4, K_5 is 4 connected, but K_5 /e is K_4 and it is 3 connected.

Comment: @MishaLavrov   this example does not at least k+2 vertices :(